# Can I use third party xml library for PIC32

Tags: xml, embedded, pic32

I am using PIC32 to design a Bluetooth application. The PIC32 has to send and receive XML information to and from android phone through Bluetooth. However, I couldn't find any XML library provided by Microchip. I need to use a third party for XML.

Can I use third part XML library for PIC32?

The one I am gonna use is: http://xmlsoft.org/ or http://www.jclark.com/xml/expat.html.

Comment: You have to give more details.

Comment: To expand on Daniel's comment: what compiler?  Do you have an RTOS?  Is the rest of your implementation in C?  As an aside, both of the parsers you linked to seem to be very heavy weight (both are full-on libraries for PC OS's).  You'd be better off trying to find something more suited for small-scale work.

Comment: The compiler is xc32. I don't have RTOS. The rest of my implementation is done in C.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly do not have to have a PIC32 specific library much less one provided from Microchip.

I would not imagine an XML library would any system dependency beyond a standard library, and even if it did that may be a component that you do not need and can simply remove or stub.

I would expect that if the source compiles with your toolchain, you are good to go. If it does not due to dependencies, you can address that in a number of ways:

- Remove components that are not needed,
- Provide non-working stubs,
- Provide working replacements,
- Add additional libraries to resolve dependencies.

The behaviour of the library with respect to memory usage may be more critical if your system is memory constrained or perhaps if you provide no heap.